# Asp Core, check if user is in Role in Identity 1.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, role-base-authorization

I am using asp.net core 1.1 and identity 1.1. There are 2 roles in my application contains "Admin" and "User". I want "Admin" users navigate to "/AdminProfile/Index" after login and "User" users navigate to "/UserProfile/Index" after login.

**My Login Code :**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**And in RedirectToLocal Action :**

```
    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {

            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return Redirect("/AdminProfile/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/UserProfile/Index");
            }

        }
    }
```

I use `User.IsInRole("Admin")` to verify user role but it always returns false. How can i check user role in identity 1.1?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369157/user-isinrole-return-false) answer, it should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I can solved it after many research. Try it :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                string existingRole = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single();

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl,existingRole);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }





    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl,string roleName)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (roleName == "Admin")
            {
                return Redirect("/Admin/User");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/User/UserProfile");
            }

        }
    }
```